# How to attach template to the page

Tags: php, wordpress

i am creating my own plugin..

**my code is**

```
 function createTable()
{
  global $user_ID;
  $page['post_type']    = 'page';
  $page['post_content'] = 'hello this page created by plugin';
  $page['post_parent']  = 0;
  $page['post_author']  = $user_ID;
  $page['post_status']  = 'publish';
  $page['post_title']   = 'dpage';
  $pageid = wp_insert_post ($page);
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->query("insert into wp_postmeta(post_id,meta_key,meta_value) values (".$pageid.",'_wp_page_template','c1.php')");   
}
```

the above code is working fine for me.

my question is here i am assigning template **c1.php** to my newly created page. but for that i have to copy **c1.php** in to my theme directory only....

but i want to attach **c1.php** template from my plugin directory....

can you suggest me how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to assign the page template meta. Using the filter [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) and checking for the page slug, we can load a template from inside the plugin's folder:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'plugin_template_so_19681471' );

function plugin_template_so_19681471( $template )
{
    if( is_page( 'dpage' ) )
        # the file is located at the same level as the plugin main file
        $template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/c1.php'; 

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the slug of the page is `dpage`? You can use ID with `is_page()` too. And is the file `c1.php` at the same level as the main plugin file? I tested it in a mini-plugin and works ok for me.

Comment: how to find slug? sorry i am newbie in wordpress... it's not there in table wp_post

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40254/discussion-between-404-not-found-and-b)

Comment: Take the filter out of the function. Put it just after the activation hooks in line 10.

Comment: Follow the [`<plugin-development>`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) tag at WPSE, you'll find many examples of working plugins with all kind of cool features. Keep 404ring ;)

Answer (score 0):

first of all to add value as post meta use below function

```
update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value);
```

it will add if not exists and update if exists. here you can pass value with path you want.

Comment: i tried to add "plugins_url("c1.php",__FILE__)" and it's inserting correct path in the db also.. but it's not taking template

Comment: taking template means when trying to display?

Comment: yes it's displaying post_content rather than to display my c1.php template

Comment: then any solution? i want to use template(c1.php) from my plugin directory only...

Comment: you can use register_theme_directory( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'templates' );

Comment: it's not taking from plugin dir.. i have tried... in my db it's storing path (rootdir/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/c1.php) but then also it's not taking that template